How can I mock a method with Test::Spec?
Please help me make a unit test for the function func_for_test.
I don't understand how to mock the get_dbh function (I use Test::Spec).
ModuleForTests.pm
-----------------

use ModuleMysql;

my $dbh = get_dbh();

sub **func_for_test** {

    my $sql = "DELETE ...";
    $dbh->prepare($sql);
    ...
}

ModuleMysql.pm
-----------------

sub get_dbh {

    state $dbh = DBI->connect ...

    return $dbh;
}

I try DBD::Mock, but it did not help.
$drh = DBI->install_driver( 'Mock' );
$drh->{mock_connect_fail} = 0;
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'DBI:Mock:', '', '' );

I also try, but it did not help - error Test::Spec;
my $dbh;
BEGIN {
   $dbh = mock();
   ModuleForTests->stubs(get_dbh => $dbh);
}


Test::Spec is great for testing object oriented code. Using a lexical $dbh in a class is not a common design, an object attribute holding it is - and is much easier to mock.

I understand. But I don’t have the opportunity to rewrite the code; I have a task to test it.

Using Test::Spec forces you to write the code in a different way (which is believed to be the correct way by many).
It's better to use object oriented design for your classes if you want to use Test::Spec. Lexical $dbh populated in ModuleForTest is complex to mock, it's better to store the DB handle in an object attribute. But it's Perl and everything is possible.
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::Spec;
use Sub::Override;
use DBI;

use ModuleMysql;  # Needed here so we can override its get_dbh.

my $dbh;
BEGIN {
    $dbh = 'DBI'->connect('DBI:Mock:', "", "") or die $DBI::errstr;
}

my $override;
BEGIN {
    $override = 'Sub::Override'->new('ModuleMysql::get_dbh' => sub {
        return $dbh
    });
}

use ModuleForTest;

describe ModuleForTest => sub {
    it 'prepares delete' => sub {
        my $sth = ModuleForTest::func_for_test();
        my $history = $dbh->{mock_all_history};
        is($history->[0]->statement, 'DELETE ...');
    };
};

runtests();

The BEGIN blocks are needed, because we need to redefine the get_dbh in the precise moment after ModuleMysql has been loaded but before MoudleForTest calls it.

Thank you very much for your help, I will try to solve the problem this way.

I'm not going to address the Test::Spec part of the question, so this might not be useful for your particular case. Other people that come along might find it useful though.
The problem is that there is one method in a class that does something that gets in the way of testing. The obvious fix is to make that not a problem, but let's assume we are stuck with that. This might be the case where you are using third party code that you don't want to change since your change may disappear when an update is installed.
One of these is like what a magical module is doing for you anyway. I tend to not use modules until the value is more than the drawbacks from dependency management (and Test:: modules tend to be the worst for that).
Use a subclass
package ModuleForTest::WithoutGetDBH;
use parent ModuleForTest;

sub get_dbh { ... whatever you need ... }

At first this seems less attractive than other magical techniques, but you are already changing the meaning of the class with mocks. Something somewhere has to change, so why not use the simplest and most intended way to have a different, more specific version of a class?
There are reasons not to do this. Some modules are not designed for subclassing. That is, the authors made particular decisions that prevent subclassing.
Replace the method
I often simply replace the troublesome method. Perl is a dynamic language after all, so let's use some dynamic features. I tend to do this with third party code while I wait for a patch to be applied and released. I know I'll remove this later so I don't want to also change a pack name like I would with subclassed modules.
Load the module first then replace the definition. Last definition wins:
BEGIN {
    use ModuleForTest;
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"ModuleForTest::get_dbh"} = sub { ... whatever you want ... }
    }

Sometimes I do this locally, but usually only with code I completely control and for some reason I want to try a bunch of different situations (like, a failure one, a success one, an exception throwing one, and so on). Since these are in tests usually run sequentially, it's a special technique just for that situation:
use ModuleForTest


subtest 'something' => sub {
    local *{"ModuleForTest::get_dbh"} = sub { ... whatever you want ... };
    }



You basically do what I did in my reply, with the ugliness and hackiness having a different distribution :-)

Thank you very much for your help, I will try these methods to solve my problem.
